# Empty validation on uploading csv file is not working using PHP

Tags: php, csv, upload

Good day,

Im trying to add a validation in my code where if the 'OtherSymptoms' column is empty and 'OthersSpecify' has a value, it will return a message that 'OthersSpecify' should be empty because 'OtherSymptoms' is empty.

Here is my code below:

```
if ($column === 'OtherSymptoms') {
    $validValues = ['Y', 'N'];
    $cellValue = $row[$OtherSymptoms];
    $othersSpecifyValue = $row[$OthersSpecify]; 

    if (!in_array($cellValue, $validValues)) {
    $response['errors'][] = [
        'error' => 'Invalid ' . $column . ' Value',
        'message' => '• The value for ' . $column . ' in row ' . $i . ': "' . $cellValue . '" is not valid. Accepted values are: "' . implode('" or "', $validValues) . '".'
        ];
    }

    if (empty($cellValue) && !empty($othersSpecifyValue)) {
        $response['errors'][] = [
            'error' => 'Invalid ' . $column . ' Value',
            'message' => '• The value for ' . $column . ' is empty in row ' . ($i) . ', therefore ' . $OthersSpecify . ' should not value.'
        ];
    }

    if ($cellValue === 'Y' && empty($othersSpecifyValue)) {
        $response['errors'][] = [
            'error' => 'Invalid ' . $column . ' Value',
            'message' => '• The value for ' . $column . ' is set to Y in row ' . ($i) . ', therefore ' . $OthersSpecify . ' in the sperow must not be empty.'
        ];
    }

    if ($cellValue === 'N' && !empty($othersSpecifyValue)) {
        $response['errors'][] = [
            'error' => 'Invalid ' . $column . ' Value',
            'message' => '• The value for ' . $column . ' is set to N in row ' . ($i) . ', therefore ' . $OthersSpecify . ' in the specified row must be empty.'
        ];
    }
}
```

The 'Y' and 'N' validation is working fine, but when the empty row of the column is not. I would appreciate correction and solutions. Thank you guys.

Comment: is this a typo ` '" is not valid. Accepted values areimplode('" or "', $validValues) . '"`?

Comment: yes typo only. sorry ill edit it

Comment: It seems all right for me. Maybe $row[$OtherSymptoms] need to be trimmed?

Comment: Not everything that "looks empty", must actually _be_ empty. Use `var_dump` to make debug outputs of the values in question - that will not only show your their value, but also its _length_.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($cellValue) && !empty($othersSpecifyValue)) {
    $response['errors'][] = [
        'error' => 'Invalid ' . $column . ' Value',
        'message' => '• The value for ' . $column . ' is empty in row ' . ($i) . ', therefore ' . $OthersSpecify . ' should not value.'
    ];
}
```

You are testing to see whether 'OtherSymptoms' ($cellValue) and 'OthersSpecify' ($othersSpecifyValue) are both empty. If this condition is met, you add an error message, which appears to be the inverse of what you desire. If I understand properly, you want to display an error if both 'OtherSymptoms' and 'OthersSpecify' are empty. When 'OtherSymptoms' is empty, you should change the condition to check whether 'OthersSpecify' is not empty.

```
if (empty($cellValue) && !empty($othersSpecifyValue)) {
    $response['errors'][] = [
        'error' => 'Invalid ' . $column . ' Value',
        'message' => '• The value for ' . $column . ' is empty in row ' . ($i) . ', therefore ' . $OthersSpecify . ' should be empty.'
    ];
}
```

Comment: It seems the same as above

Comment: Hi im sorry, im checking if the $cellValue is empty and the $othersSpecifyValue is not empty then i would prompt a validation error. The code you commented is the same as mine. Thanks tho